# Get laravel current route group in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Is there a way to get the parent route group of current route in Laravel middlewares?

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    // here I mean
}
```

Comment: Please give an example of what your routes are and what you expect to get as an end result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the group from a route, especially that you can nest groups within other groups.

The easiest way to be able to tell which group current request belongs to would be to add a parameter to your middleware - see the docs for more details here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-parameters

First, declare the parameter in your **handle()** method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $group = null)
{
  // your logic here
}
```

Then, when assigning middleware to groups, you can pass group name as a parameter:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'yourmiddleware:groupname'], function () {
  // your routes go here
});
```

Then in your middleware you can do different actions based on the group name passed:

```
if ($group === 'groupname') {
  // some custom logic here
}
```

If the logic you plan to do for different groups is different you should consider implementing multiple middlewares instead of passing group name as a parameter just to keep responsibilities separated.