# Identify Route's Group in Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

My ultimate objective is to limit accesses to the group of routes by validating permissions provided to the user.

***These target 'group of routes' have ONE COMMON PARENT GROUP and may have zero or more sub-groups, such that, if access to these target 'group of routes' is permitted/accessible to the user then, all its sub-route groups are also accessible to the user.***

To achieve this, I believe I need to differentiate these target group of routes by any uniqueString/parameter in middleware, which is indeed answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873135/6168395).

But, I want to generalize this further, by applying middleware to common SINGLE PARENT GROUP of all these target group of routes and identify these target group of routes by any means in the middleware.

So, my question is how do I identify/differentiate these target group of routes in the middleware? Is there any way to do so?

Sample Code of what I am trying to describe:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'singleParent','middleware' => 'permissionMiddleware'], function (){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'target-group-1', 'groupUniqueString' => 'tsg1'], function (){
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'sub-group-1.1'], function (){

        });
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'sub-group-1.2'], function (){

        });
    });
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'target-group-2', 'groupUniqueString' => 'tsg2'], function (){
        Route::get('route-1','Controller@method-of-Route1');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you not make other middlewares to your needs to restrict/access certain things for your target-group-1 and add middleware to that route::group ? the `singleParent` group and it's sub groups will follow the common middleware `permissionMiddleware` but for the sub groups you make new middlewares to handle ?

Comment: That is not required... I want to manage permissions on immediate next routeGroups of the SINGLE-PARENT group... For, sub-groups/routes of targe-group-1, they will be accessible, if the user is permitted for target-group-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to specify a route group in your middleware to handle some actions, you can do it in this way :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'singleParent','middleware' => 'permissionMiddleware'], function (){
   Route::group(['prefix' => 'target-group-1', 'as' => 'tsg1.'], function (){
       //...
   });
});
```

This will generate route names with the prefix : tsg1

Now in your middleware you can do like this to get the route group :

```
function getCurrentRouteGroup() {
   $routeName = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::current()->getName();
   return explode('.',$routeName)[0];
}
```

**Updated**

and to check :

```
if ($request->route()->named('name')) {
    //
}

return $next($request);
```

Or in another approach you can achieve :

To get the prefix of a route group you can do something like this :

```
$uri = $request->path(); 
// this will give you the url path like -> if this is the url : 
// http://localhost:8000/foo/bar you will get foo/bar
```

And then :

```
$prefix = explode('/',$uri)[0];
// and you will get 'foo'
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Your idea is nice, but I'll have to update route names everywhere else it is used, which becomes more hectic, than following middleware-parameters approach as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873135/6168395). I want to approach with minimal changes.

Comment: @nik I understand that will be a hassle, I am not sure, but can you try with this `$request->route()->getPrefix()` to get the prefix directly of a route group, I have used this when I was using L5, I am not sure it supports now or not. then you can just compare prefixes as your needs and implement rules in your middleware.

Comment: @nik let me if this works, or I have another idea, I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, it worked! But, still, can you share your another idea?

Comment: Your approach with path and prefix are almost similar. Both works... Thanks!

Comment: @nik Yes, you can use any way you like. Glad to help you out ! If you think my answer solves your problem then mark as solved this question. Thanks